# Does arm work with the version 3.5 of Tor browser bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, nyx, ubuntu

I thought I would try monitoring Tor with arm instead of Vidalia, but I keep getting errors. 
I am running Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Comment: It certainly should be possible. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I keep getting:Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this would help:
[How to use Arm with Tor Browser Bundle](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/how-to-use-arm-with-tor-browser-bundle?rq=1)