# How to use Arm with Tor Browser Bundle

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, nyx

Tor Browser Bundle 3.5 doesn't maintain Vidalia Tor map anymore, so I thought of using Tor Arm to view the Tor network traffic. How do I run it?

Comment: Which OS are you using for this?

Answer (score 5):

Do this to connect to the Tor provided by TBB.

```
$ ./arm -i 127.0.0.1:9151
Controller password: ****
```